# Power BI : Slicer does not work after the report is published

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop, slicers, power-bi-report-server

We are using Power BI Report server on premise and we were looking for a slicer containing a search bar in order to facilitate the selection for users, for this we used (Smart filter by OKVIZ) which worked perfectly on Desktop but does not work after the publication of the report.

I would very much appreciate if you could help us solve this problem.

Comment: It maybe due to the PBIRS not supporting the api use in the visual.

Comment: The slicer is certified by Microsoft, and the issue occurs even when I'm using other slicers with search bar